# What's about the convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{C(2\sqrt{k})}{k^{5/2}},$ where $C(x)$ is the Fresnel C integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fresnel-integrals

One can calculate a closed-form of (this or different examples) $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{C(2\sqrt{k})}{k^{5/2}},$$ where $C(x)$ is the [Fresnel C integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FresnelIntegrals.html) from the Fourier expansion of the fractional part function $ \left\{ x \right\} $, multiplying by a factor and integrating: $$\int_0^1 (x-\frac{1}{2})\sqrt{x}dx=-\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k}\int_0^1\sin(2\pi k x)\sqrt{x}dx.$$
From here you need this integration (also another in LHS) *integrate sin(2pi kx) (sqrt(x)) dx, from x=0 to 1*, this is the Wolfram Alpha code, and after do the sum. I don't know if this *trick* and series are well known or interesting (I am calculating and manipulating different examples), but I am interested in ask it here to answer this

> **Question.** It's easy to prove with the definition of the Fresnel C integral that our series is convergent, and as I've said it is easy to get it in a closed-form, but imagine that we need answer the following exercise:
>
> **Do a study of the speed of convergence of our integral.**  That is, let $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{C(2\sqrt{k})}{k^{5/2}},$$ then study and convince us about if our series converges more or less quickly (you can do those comparisons that you need), and convince us if it's possible improve this speed of such  convergence. That's is, how one does a rigurous study of the convergence of our series? **Thanks in advance.**

Comment: I am asking thus: How one does study and specify the speed of convergence of this series?, and if it is possible improve the speed of convergence of our series. How do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the definition of $C(z)$ we have
$$ C(2\sqrt{k}) = \int_{0}^{2\sqrt{k}}\cos\left(\tfrac{\pi x^2}{2}\right)\,dx = \int_{0}^{k}\frac{\cos(2\pi t)}{\sqrt{t}}\,dt = \sqrt{\frac{k}{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(k u)}{\sqrt{u}}\,du$$
hence, in particular,
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{C(2\sqrt{k})}{k^{5/2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(\color{blue}{\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{\cos(ku)}{k^2}}\right)\frac{du}{\sqrt{u}} $$
where (over the interval $(0,2\pi)$) the blue series is the Fourier series of a [Bernoulli polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials),
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{\cos(ku)}{k^2} = \frac{u^2}{4}-\frac{\pi u}{2}+\frac{\pi^2}{6} $$
leading, by uniform convergence, to:
$$\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{C(2\sqrt{k})}{k^{5/2}}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(\frac{u^{3/2}}{4}-\frac{\pi\sqrt{u}}{2}+\frac{\pi^2}{6\sqrt{u}}\right)\,du = \color{red}{\frac{\pi^2}{15}}.$$

Comment: Many thanks, now I will study your answer. It's possible do a sumary about the speed of convergence of such series? That is, imagine that someone ask me what's about the speed of convergence of this series? How I can quantify it? It is possible always improve the speed of convergence of a series of this kind? Or it is very difficult to deduce? Many thanks always for your great answers.

Comment: @user243301: since $\cos(x^2)$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}^+$, the asymptotic behaviour of $C(2\sqrt{k})$ is just $O(1)$, and the speed of convergence is the same as $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{k^{5/2}}$.

Comment: Then many thanks, I need study and refresh this recipes.

Comment: nice, deserves more upvotes (+1)